# Is there a way to achieve partitioning while using Flink Broadcast pattern?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

[This](https://flink.apache.org/2020/03/24/advanced-flink-application-patterns-vol.2-dynamic-updates-of-application-logic/) example provides a use case where an operator needs whole elements of a first datastream while processing one element of the other (second) datastream.

Is broadcasting pattern only way to achieve this so that second stream elements can reach the whole collection of the first stream?

If that is the case how can we achieve the same partitioning as the second one (let's say we partition the second one by client id and the same also is in the elements of the first stream). As far as I looked around we cannot use keyBy on a broadcasted stream or vice versa.

> Flink assumes that broadcasted data needs to be stored and retrieved
> while processing events of the main data flow and, therefore, always
> automatically creates a corresponding broadcast state from this state
> descriptor.
> Blockquote

```java
     DataStream<Alert> alerts =
         transactions
             .connect(rulesStream)
             .process(new DynamicKeyFunction())
             .keyBy((keyed) -> keyed.getKey())
             .connect(rulesStream)
             .process(new DynamicAlertFunction())


    public class DynamicKeyFunction
        extends BroadcastProcessFunction<Transaction, Rule, Keyed<Transaction, String, Integer>> {
    
    
      @Override
      public void processBroadcastElement(Rule rule,
                                         Context ctx,
                                         Collector<Keyed<Transaction, String, Integer>> out) {
        BroadcastState<Integer, Rule> broadcastState = ctx.getBroadcastState(RULES_STATE_DESCRIPTOR);
        broadcastState.put(rule.getRuleId(), rule);
      }
    
      @Override
      public void processElement(Transaction event,
                               ReadOnlyContext ctx,
                               Collector<Keyed<Transaction, String, Integer>> out){
        ReadOnlyBroadcastState<Integer, Rule> rulesState =
                                      ctx.getBroadcastState(RULES_STATE_DESCRIPTOR);
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Rule> entry : rulesState.immutableEntries()) {
            final Rule rule = entry.getValue();
            out.collect(
              new Keyed<>(
                event, KeysExtractor.getKey(rule.getGroupingKeyNames(), event), rule.getRuleId()));
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to process two streams together, where both are key-partitioned, that's possible, but it does not involved broadcasting. This is discussed in the documentation in https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/etl/#connected-streams